# What's the Atelier Rorona Plus Premium Box?

Tags: atelier-rorona

On the [wiki](http://atelier.wikia.com/wiki/Atelier_Rorona:_The_Alchemist_of_Arland#New_Atelier_Rorona) in the 4th paragraph talking about the new stuff in Atelier Ronona Plus

> The "Premium Box" editions of the game also differs slightly in content between the PS3 and PS Vita versions

however as far as i know there's only 1 version available to download for each, what is this "Premium Box" and how is it different to the normal versions for the PS3 and Vita and the PS3 and Vita versions of itself?

Comment: Sounds like a boxed release to me rather than a download.

Comment: @Mario as far as i know even in the US it was a digital download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Premium box was a boxed edition in Japan. Came with a poster, little crystal cube with the game logo etched inside it, a decal, and the game. I believe all the Atelier Plus games have had basically the same thing.

Here's Atelier Totori with some good pictures.

http://nisamerica.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=10240&start=165#p539141